# java code for capture the image by webcam UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jmf

I am using windows7 64 bit operating system. The source code is for capturing the image by webcam:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.util.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*;

public class SwingCapture extends Panel implements ActionListener 
{
  public static Player player = null;
  public CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
  public MediaLocator ml = null;
  public JButton capture = null;
  public Buffer buf = null;
  public Image img = null;
  public VideoFormat vf = null;
  public BufferToImage btoi = null;
  public ImagePanel imgpanel = null;

  public SwingCapture() 
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(320,550);

    imgpanel = new ImagePanel();
    capture = new JButton("Capture");
    capture.addActionListener(this);

    String str1 = "vfw:Logitech USB Video Camera:0";
    String str2 = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
    di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(str2);
    ml = di.getLocator();

    try 
    {
      player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
      player.start();
      Component comp;

      if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null)
      {
        add(comp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      }
      add(capture,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(imgpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Frame f = new Frame("SwingCapture");
    SwingCapture cf = new SwingCapture();

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
      playerclose();
      System.exit(0);}});

    f.add("Center",cf);
    f.pack();
    f.setSize(new Dimension(320,550));
    f.setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void playerclose() 
  {
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
    JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();

    if (c == capture) 
    {
      // Grab a frame
      FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl)
      player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
      buf = fgc.grabFrame();

      // Convert it to an image
      btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
      img = btoi.createImage(buf);

      // show the image
      imgpanel.setImage(img);

      // save image
      saveJPG(img,"c:\\test.jpg");
    }
  }

  class ImagePanel extends Panel 
  {
    public Image myimg = null;

    public ImagePanel() 
    {
      setLayout(null);
      setSize(320,240);
    }

    public void setImage(Image img) 
    {
      this.myimg = img;
      repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
      if (myimg != null) 
      {
        g.drawImage(myimg, 0, 0, this);
      }
    }
  }


  public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s)
  {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img, null, null);

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    { 
      out = new FileOutputStream(s); 
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException io)
    { 
      System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
    }

    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
    param.setQuality(0.5f,false);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);

    try 
    { 
      encoder.encode(bi); 
      out.close(); 
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException io) 
    {
      System.out.println("IOException"); 
    }
  }

}
```

This code is sucessfully compiled. On running the code, the following runtime error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:JMFSecurityManager: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:no jmvfw in 
java.library.path at com.sun.media.JMFSecurityManager.loadLibrary(JMFSecurityManager.java:206)
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWCapture.<clinit><VFWCapture.java:19>
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.doConnect(VFWSourceStream.java:241)
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.run(VFWSourceStream.java:763)
at java.cdlang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please send me solution of this problem/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution but I haven't tried it: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10191973

Basically, what it says is uninstall 64 bit jdk and install 32 bit instead.